Electrical insulation properties of flexible magnets
What thickness of rubber or pvc, ferrite or neodymium, magnet is required to electrically insulate a 12awg 120v 20amp wire for general commercial usage?
Tables, charts, formulae for different materials and electrical wiring?
Many thanks!

This isn't a physics question, since you're asking about general commercial usage.  You might try asking at the Home Improvement site: https://diy.stackexchange.com

Many physics questions have commercial applications. No one at an home improvement site would have this type of information. Please consider answering the question. Thanks.

What you are asking is NOT a physics question.  The Home Improvement site is more likely to have someone who can point you in the right direction than this site, which is why I pointed you there.
